# Does $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist if $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ doesn't, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$ does?

Tags: limits

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ doesn't exist, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x)]$ exists, what can be said about $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$?

So I think that the answer is that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ doesn't exist. And I tried proving it by getting a contradiction.

Let's assume that  $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ doesn't exist and that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x)] = L$ and that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) = K$.
Because there is no  $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ that means that $$\lim\limits_{x\to a+} f(x) = M \neq N = \lim\limits_{x\to a-} f(x). $$
Because there is  $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ that means that $$\lim\limits_{x\to a+} g(x) = K = \lim\limits_{x\to a-} g(x). $$
Now, $$L=\lim\limits_{x\to a+} [f(x) + g(x)]= \lim\limits_{x\to a+} f(x) + \lim\limits_{x\to a+} g(x)= M + K$$
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to a-} [f(x) + g(x)]= \lim\limits_{x\to a-} f(x) + \lim\limits_{x\to a-} g(x)= N + K$$
$$\Rightarrow M + N = N + K  \Rightarrow M = N $$
which is a contradiction with $M \neq N$

Is any of this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $M$ and $N$? Maybe it does not have left and right limits too.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. I totally didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it exists, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}[(f(x)+g(x))-g(x)]=\lim\limits_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))-\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$$ exists. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It was really simple but for some odd reason I always make things more complicated than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact: $\lim f+g=\lim f+\lim g$.

Comment: This is not a fact, and wrong in this situation.

Comment: We can't use this because it is only equal to it if both $\lim f$ and  $\lim g$ exist

Comment: @user155200 Yes, but if lim g exists, then we can show (lim f+g) - lim g is the limit of f. Of course, when you write down such equation, the existence of limit is implicitly assumed.